# I need to preserve a tape using symantec backup exec. I'm aving trouble doing so

Tags: windows, backup-exec

Please forgive me if this is the wrong stack exchange site. Please suggest which one I should post this to if it is.

There's an automatic tape machine running in a remote location, with software (symantec backup exec 11d)   Recently one of the servers being backed up had problems with its raid controller, so one of the drives has become invisible.

I need to preserve the last good backup of that drive so I am trying to replace the tape with the most recent backup of that drive on it with one of the scratch tapes (blank tapes) present in the machine.  I've tried the following...

- Associate the blank media with the media set in question (Wednesday)
- For the existing media (the tape with the data I want to keep) I click 'move to vault' and move it to the offline vault.
- I associate it with something other than 'Wednesday' (a media set called 'keep data infinitely...')
- I then do an inventory on that slot.

The above steps I'm led to believe are supposed to put the fresh tape in the slot that had the tape I want to keep in it.  But it just keeps showing up as containing the tape I want to keep after the inventory. (after refreshing the device tree)

I am a complete newbie with this software.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong, and/or tell me how to acheive my desired goal

Edit:  Just want to point out that I did try to get help directly from symantec with this,  but having jumped through countless hoops to create an account and create a support ticket my progress was halted by requiring something called a 'tecnical contact id' at the final step with no explanation of what it is or how to get one.

Answer (score 0):

You require a current maintenance account with Symantec. Running 11D it is unlikley you have one.

Have you run an Inventory  and a Catalog?

Try this:

Navigate to the Device tab and on each tape slot, right-click it and choose Catalog. This will import the tape's directory information.

Comment: If I do this will I then be able to get the scratch tape to move to the slot that was being used by the other tape (the tape I want to 'put to one side' and keep the data stored on.)

Comment: I did this,  but I'm not sure how relevant it is to my problem.  I still can't get the tape to come out of the rotation.